# Adding configuration packages results in failing to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: java, gradle, log4j2, slf4j

I am working on a Java Spring Boot project.

Once I edit the log4j2.yml to add packages under configurations, I get an SLF4J error saying:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"
```

Example for the relevant part in the file:

```
Configuration:
  packages: io.myproject.myservice.configuration.log4j2
  status: ${env:LOG_LEVEL:-info}
```

It is important to note that it doesn't matter what the package will be, as long as the "packages:" entry exists, with a package in the configuration, the error above arises.

Usually this error means that the underlying Logging Implementation cannot be found.

When I check the Gradle packages, I can see that the log4j2 required dependencies are in place:

```
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.4.1 -> 2.13.3
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.4.1 -> 2.13.3
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.4.1 -> 2.13.3
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.4.1 -> 2.13.3
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.4.1 -> 2.13.3
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.4.1 -> 2.13.3
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.4.1 -> 2.13.3
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.4.1 -> 2.12.1 (*)
```

The used version according to the output should be 2.12.1 for log4j-core and log4j-api.

run time configurations:

```
gradle dependencies | grep -A100  runtimeClasspath | grep log4j

+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:1.3.8.RELEASE
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.4.1 -> 2.13.3
|    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.3
|    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.13.3 -> 2.11.2
|    |         \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.2 -> 2.13.3
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.4.1 -> 2.13.3
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.4.1 -> 2.11.2 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:1.3.8.RELEASE (*)
```

What might cause the issue?
How can this be debugged?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with `gradle dependencies` command , the (*) mean that this is previously listed.

So you do have a conflict with dependencies that already use SLF4J.

My suggestion is that you can try to follow their official doc [here](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) which was helpful for me to fix the issue, or you can find the other dependencies and exclude SLF4J.

Comment: where do you see the conflict for example? the "->" shows the selected versions and the selected versions seem to match o.k.